# Question I answered about 3 hours ago has disappeared

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, specific-user, specific-answer

I answered [this question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272745/finding-operator-a-in-l-ell-1-ell-2-norm) about 3 hours ago correctly. The user seems to have deleted the entire thread including my answer.

Is this really what happened and if so, is this behaviour accepted on MSE?

**Edit:**

Now it seems the answer has been found. Is there anything that can be done about it? For example can the original question be undeleted?

Comment: Was it possibly [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1272665) instead? That question was deleted.

Comment: The [deleted version](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1272639/11619). This is not ok. Reasking the same question with exact same wording is "never" ok IMO (for a suitable definition of *never*). The OP's answer stands at -2.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Ok, should I flag for moderator attention? Or not in this case because I already asked a meta post?

Comment: @robjohn Possibly. But it says page not found.

Comment: You can flag the repeat question. Unless you have a link, it may be difficult for you to even locate the older version. Remember: only users with 10000+ rep can "see" deleted threads. Robjohn and I gave the link for the benefit of such users.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, impossible for me to locate it. I will go and flag his new post...

Comment: @user213845: since two moderators are commenting here, you probably don't need to flag.

Comment: @robjohn Okay, I will not flag.

Comment: @robjohn Is it possible for you to undelete the previous question?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  I wanted to comment on your comment to the answer in the new question but don't have enough reputation... the result $\|A\|=2$ is correct. I believe he did notice that there are two norms. His answer is similar to mine although slightly more high level and less explicit.

Comment: Would moving user213845's answer to the undeleted question be a reasonable solution here? (At least solution with whih user213845 would be satisfied?) If yes, are moderators able to do such thing? (I know that mods can merge questions. I am not sure, if it is the case for deleted questions, too.)

Comment: @user213845: I have undeleted [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1272665) temporarily. As soon as you copy it, I will delete it again.

Comment: @robjohn Thank you, I copy pasted it.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't of much help in the end. I got distracted by the question. Mind you, I think $||A||=\sqrt2$ ;-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You were plenty of help, thank you!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: That's what Randall called "nerd-sniped" =D. So at the end the answer by user213845 is not copied there?

Comment: @justhalf: As in [here](https://xkcd.com/356/)? ;-) user213845's answer was copied there all right. They later realized the error, and self-deleted the answer (meaning that 10k+ users can still see it).